# ASP.NET Client to Server communication

Tags: asp.net, callback, updatepanel, postback

Can you help me make sense of all the different ways to communicate from browser to client in ASP.NET?  I have made this a community wiki so feel free to edit my post to improve it.  Specifically, I'm trying to understand in which scenario to use each one by listing how each works.

I'm a little fuzzy on UpdatePanel vs CallBack (with ViewState): I know UpdatePanel always returns HTML while CallBack can return JSON.  Any other major differences?

...and CallBack (without ViewState) vs WebMethod.  CallBack goes through most of the Page lifecycle, WebMethod doesn't.  Any other major differences?

### [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx)

- Custom handler for anything (page, image, etc.)

  - Only does what you tell it to do (**light server processing, light traffic**)
  - [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) is an implementation of [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx)
  - If you don't need what [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) provides, create a custom [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx)
  - If you are using [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) but overriding [`Render()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20b8wk8d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and not generating HTML, you probably can do it with a custom [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) (e.g. writing binary data such as images)
- By default can use the .axd or .ashx file extensions -- both are functionally similar

  - .ashx doesn't have any built-in endpoints, so it's preferred by convention

### Regular PostBack ([System.Web.UI.Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) : [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx))

- Inherits [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx)

  - Full PostBack, including [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) and HTML control values (**heavy traffic**)
  - Full [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) [lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) (**heavy server processing**)
- No JavaScript required
- Webpage flickers/scrolls since everything is reloaded in browser
- Returns full page HTML (**heavy traffic**)

### [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) ([System.Web.UI.Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.aspx))

- Control inside [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx)

  - Full PostBack, including [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) and HTML control values (**heavy traffic**)
  - Full [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) [lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) (**heavy server processing**)
  - Controls outside the [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) do Render(NullTextWriter)
- Must use [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx)

  - If no client-side JavaScript, it can fall back to regular PostBack with no JavaScript (?)
- No flicker/scroll since it's an async call, unless it falls back to regular postback.
- Can be used with master pages and user controls
- Has built-in support for progress bar
- Returns HTML for controls inside [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) (**medium traffic**)

### [Client CallBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx) ([Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx),  [System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.icallbackeventhandler.aspx))

- Inherits [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx)

  - Most of [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) [lifecycle](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET_Server_Doc/developer/ADF/ajax_callback.htm) - no render but control tree has to be created (**heavy server processing**)
- Takes only data you specify (**light traffic**) and optionally [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) (?) (**medium traffic**)
- Client must support JavaScript and use [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx)
- No flicker/scroll since it's an async call
- Can be used with master pages and user controls
- Returns only data you specify in format you specify (e.g. JSON, XML...) (?) (**light traffic**)
- During a callback, the page must add the associated control at the same location in the control tree, otherwise an Exception occurs.

### [WebMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28VS.71%29.aspx) ([System.Web.Service.WebService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webservice.aspx))

- Considered legacy technology.  [Should use WCF service instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738737.aspx).
- Class implements [System.Web.Service.WebService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webservice.aspx)

  - [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) available through [`this.Context`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webservice.context.aspx)
- Takes only data you specify (**light traffic**)
- Server only runs the called method (**light server processing**)
- Client must support JavaScript
- No flicker/scroll since it's an async call
- Can be used with master pages and user controls
- Returns only data you specify, typically JSON (**light traffic**)

  - Can create instance of server control to render HTML and sent back as string, but events, paging in GridView, etc. won't work

### [PageMethods](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx)

- Essentially a [WebMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28VS.71%29.aspx) contained in the [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) class, so most of [WebMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28VS.71%29.aspx)'s bullet's apply

  - As with [WebMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28VS.71%29.aspx), legacy technology and WCF Service should be used.
  - Method must be `public static`, therefore no [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) instance accessible
  - [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) available through [`HttpContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx)
- Accessed directly by URL `Page.aspx/MethodName` (e.g. with [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) directly or [with library such as jQuery](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/))

  - Setting `ScriptManager` property `EnablePageMethods="True"` [generates a JavaScript proxy](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) for each [WebMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28VS.71%29.aspx)
- *Cannot* be used directly in user controls
- with master pages and user controls

### [WCF Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx)

- Supersedes [WebMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28VS.71%29.aspx) and [PageMethods](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx)
- Interface has [ServiceContract attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.aspx)
- Method has [OperationContract attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.aspx)
- Same benefits as WebMethod, plus more flexible

### Any others?

Comment: Not a correction but just a useful tip on the `WebMethod` attribute. It has the `EnableSession` setting which can be helpful (I think this setting is false by default).

Comment: Another thing I'm considering is ScriptManager vs jQuery. One nice thing about ScriptManager is the proxies it creates for WebMethods--the rest stinks. If we should be using WCF anyway, that benefit is gone. The only reason I currently see to use ScriptManager at all is if you want the benefits (and drawbacks) server controls provide in an UpdatePanel.  Or, if you want to use the AJAX Control Toolkit.

Comment: And for callbacks: other than encapsulating everything into a user control, is there any real benefit compared to a web service?  If not, one less reason to use ScriptManager.  If you can use the server controls with full postbacks or not use them at all, you don't need ScriptManager.  If you bind on every PostBack, you don't need full ViewState.  If you purely use AJAX, you don't need control state.  If you don't need ViewState/control state and ScriptManager, you might as well go ASP.NET MVC.  Am I flawed in my logic here?

Answer (score 2):

`WebMethod` is used with ASMX web services, which Microsoft now considers to be "legacy technology". WCF services should be used instead. They support both SOAP over HTTP/HTTPS and REST-based or JSON services, so are much more flexible.

For this reason, I also recommend against `PageMethods`, even if they seem to be convenient.

Answer (score 0):

For ICallbackEventHandler

1. ViewState is always sent to the server in the ajax request, so it can be read and control state can be re-instantiated, but the ViewState is not updated on the server, or sent back to the browser in the ajax response.
2. Form values are posted back to the server in the request.