# calling a server side function from javascript without using ajax

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to do the following :

```
function redirectContactOnClick(contactId) {
            var enc=<%= QueryStringModule.Encrypt("cont="+ contactId)%>;
            alert(enc);
            //window.location = "Contacts/AddEditContact.aspx";
        }
```

`QueryStringModule.Encrypt` is a function inside a `c# class`, the page raise an error saying :`The name 'contactId' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Post your class, please. contactId is private?

Comment: i updated my question , i don't think the class is causing the issue :/

Comment: Are you aware that JS is executed on the client (browser), and C# on the server?
Your C# code (compiler, actually) has no idea what contactId is.

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828803/how-to-call-code-behind-server-method-from-a-client-side-javascript-function

Comment: @Sora: You have to send the contactId from the client to the server *somehow*. Ajax is the first option you should reach for to do that. A statement like "I don't want to use [the obvious first choice]" really needs to be accompanied by ***why not***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to pass your javascript variable (`contactId`) to C# method. Suggest to look a different solution for that, for example, making Generic Web Handler (.ashx) and pass there your contactId via ajax and get back whatever you expect from your `Encrypt` call.

Comment: i don't want to use ajax

Comment: As alternative you can build another page that accepts **contactId** and will just redirect you to different page which will encrypt your contractid and redirect to Contacts/AddEditContact.aspx or wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can call Server side(C#) function from javascript.
First you have include your script inside a ScriptManager runnable at server.
Then the javascript function can call the c# function (which is having an attribute of (`[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]` and must be static) can be accessed.

eg.

```
 PageMethods.QueryStringModule.Encrypt("cont="+ contactId);
```

on client-side, and

```
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
  public static void Encrypt(string id)
  {
       // Do something
  };
```

on server-side

(Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/727256/how-to-call-server-side-function-from-javascript)

Comment: Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/727256/how-to-call-server-side-function-from-javascript

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can just click on [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26299112/edit) if you want to change something in your post, so there is no need to use comments for that.

Answer (score 0):

For to call the Server Side member the only mode is do a request HTTP or sync (POST Page) o async (AJAX)

you don't call a server function directly

in the you case

receive an error because **contactId** not is an page's member you can comunicate with these way

[ASP.NET Client to Server communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017394/asp-net-client-to-server-communication)